# Best way (preferably numpythonic) to count the length before value changes occur, and number of transitions, in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Sorry if the title is a little confusing, but I'll explain more here. Say I have a large array with a small number of unique elements that looks like this:

```py
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
               [0,2,0,0,1,1,1],
               [0,2,0,0,1,1,1],
               [0,2,1,1,1,0,0],
               [0,3,2,2,0,2,1])
```

In this case, the array is 5x6 for example purposes, but in reality, I could be working with something as large as a 10000x10000 array (still with a small amount of unique elements).

I was wondering how to iterate through each rows and 'count' the amount of times the array element changes as you move from right to left, as well as the number of constant elements between transitions.

For example, in the above array, the first row has 1 transition, and lengths 2 and 5 for the values 0 and 1, respectively. In the second-to-last row, there are 3 transitions, with lengths 1, 1, 2, and 2, for the values 0, 2, 1, and 0, respectively.

Ideally, some function `transition_count` would take `arr` above and return the something like:

```
row0: [1, (0,2), (1,5)]
row1: [3, (0,1), (2,1), (0,2), (1,3)]
row2: ...
```

and so forth.

My thinking for this is to iterate through each row of the array, `arr[i,:]`, and analyze it separately (maybe as a list?). But even for just a single row, I'm not sure how to 'count' the number of transitions and the obtain length of each constant element.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: A high-level design discussion is generally out of scope for Stack Overflow.  This seems to be a difficulty in problem analysis, rather than a Stack Overflow issue.  You *might* get some help if you focus your question and repost to the `algorithm` tag.  Also see ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This points out features to avoid in your rewrite.

Comment: @Prune Ah okay, so perhaps I can just focus on the part of counting transition and constant element lengths in a 1-D array, and avoid talking about arrays all together? And then once I am able to do this for a 1-D array, I can scale it to the larger problem myself.

Comment: That's a good line of attack.  You could also try looking for a discussion site, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on a per-row basis. Not sure we can readily vectorize further given the jagged nature of the output.

```
for row in arr:
    d = np.diff(row) != 0
    idx = np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(d) + 1))
    c = np.diff(np.concatenate((idx, [len(row)])))
    print(len(c))
    print('v', row[idx])
    print('c', c)
```

Here is a fully vectorized solution, if you are willing to accept a slightly different output format:

```
d = np.diff(arr, axis=1) != 0
t = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
t[:, 1:] = d
e = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
e[:, :-1] = d
sr, sc = np.nonzero(t)
er, ec = np.nonzero(e)
v = arr[sr, sc]

print(sr)
print(sc)
print(v)
print(ec-sc + 1)
```

Note: you can group and split there outputs by sr to arrive at your original stated format; but usually it is best to stay away from jagged arrays entirely if you can (and you almost always can!), also in any downstream processing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way to get all values and counts -

```
# Look for interval changes and pad with bool 1s on either sides to set the
# first interval for each row and for setting boundary wrt the next row
p = np.ones((len(a),1), dtype=bool)
m = np.hstack((p, a[:,:-1]!=a[:,1:], p))

# Look for interval change indices in flattened array version
intv = m.sum(1).cumsum()-1

# Get index and counts
idx = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(m.ravel()))  
count = np.delete(idx, intv[:-1])
val = a[m[:,:-1]]
```

To get to the final split ones split based on rows -

```
# Get couples and setup offsetted interval change indices
grps = np.c_[val,count]
intvo = np.r_[0,intv-np.arange(len(intv))]

# Finally slice and get output
out = [grps[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(intvo[:-1], intvo[1:])]
```

#### Benchmarking

Solution to get counts and values as functions :

```
# @Eelco Hoogendoorn's soln
def eh(arr):
    d = np.diff(arr, axis=1) != 0
    t = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    t[:, 1:] = d
    e = np.ones(shape=arr.shape, dtype=np.bool)
    e[:, :-1] = d
    sr, sc = np.nonzero(t)
    er, ec = np.nonzero(e)
    v = arr[sr, sc]
    return ec-sc + 1,v

# Function form of proposed solution from this post
def grouped_info(a):
    p = np.ones((len(a),1), dtype=bool)
    m = np.hstack((p, a[:,:-1]!=a[:,1:], p))
    intv = m.sum(1).cumsum()-1
    idx = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(m.ravel()))  
    count = np.delete(idx, intv[:-1])
    val = a[m[:,:-1]]
    return count,val
```

We will try to get closer to your actual use-case scenario of `10000x10000` by tiling the given sample along the two axes and time the proposed solutions.

```
In [48]: a
Out[48]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1]])

In [49]: a = np.repeat(np.repeat(a,1000,axis=0),1000,axis=1)

In [50]: %timeit grouped_info(a)
126 ms ± 7.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [52]: %timeit eh(a)
389 ms ± 41.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```